# Where to put the "+" in "200-word" to mean "200 or more words"?

Tags: punctuation

I wrote this:

> Write a 200-word essay.

However, I need to indicate that it should be at least 200-words. For brevity, I'd like to place "+". I've tried these:

- 200+-word
- +200-word
- 200-word+

Which way is correct in formal or technical writing?

Comment: _Write an essay of 200 (+) words._ (The greater-than-or-equal-to sign is also available.) However, it is arguable that 'formal writing' demands the exceedingly laborious _Write an essay of 200 words or more._ Some might even demand that you spell out 'two hundred'. At least it's not you writing the essay.

Comment: *Write a 200-word, or longer, essay.*

Comment: I think I would say, 'Write an essay of at least 200 words'!

Comment: I agree with @EdwinAshworth. Furthermore, all of your choices are confusing and could be mistaken for a typing mistake. Clarity is always better than brevity if brevity cannot fix the problem; hence, I would write, "Write an essay of at least 200 words." EDIT: WS2 beat me to it by a few seconds!

Comment: Conforming to the format of the question, the answer would be, *200+ word*; no hyphen is needed even though it is an adjectival phrase.

Answer (score 5):

The comments are spot on in that *in formal or technical* writing you would spell it out, as "of at least 200 words" or "of 200 words or more", or what have you.

But to still answer the question for not-so-formal writing: out of the three options you are considering, only "200+-word" is an option, and something that I see people use, too. The other two are clearly nonsensical, to the extent that I can't recall ever encountering them at all, not even in the wilderness of the Internet.

Comment: I could see "200+-word" being confusing, since "+-" looks very similar to "+/-" to mean "give or take" or "about". If the writing is less formal, I would still recommend 200+ word essay. Yes, the hyphen is lacking, but I don't think it creates any ambiguity or confusion.

Comment: I don't see much wrong with **200-word+** As I would say: **200 words or more** before I would say **200 or more words**.